# internal_relocation Error with ARMv7 simulator

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to translate c code below into assembly for a assignment

```
int sqrtIter(int a, int xi, int cnt, int k, int t)
{
   for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
   {
        int step = ((xi*xi-a)*xi)>>k;
        if (step > t)
           step = t;
        else if(step< -t)
           step = -t;
        xi = xi - step;
   }
   return xi;
}

int x = sqrtIter(168, 1, 100, 10, 2); // Output: 13
```

and here's the assembly code I have

```
.global _start

a:      .word 168
xi:     .word 1
cnt:    .word 100
k:      .word 10
t:      .word 2
x:      .space 4
_start:
    //use R0 for i set R0 to 0
    MOV R0, #0
    //load cnt into R1
    LDR R1, =cnt
    //use R2 for step int
    LDR R2, #0
    //load xi into R3
    LDR R3, =xi
    //load a into R4
    LDR R4, =a
    //load k into R5
    LDR R5, =k
    //load t into R6
    LDR R6, =t

LOOP:
    
    CMP R0, R1  //i-cnt
    BGE END     //branch to end if i>=n
    //R7 for (xi*xi)(step is R7)
    MUL R7, R3, R3
    //reuse R7 to -a
    SUB R7, R7, R4
    //multiply by xi again
    MUL R7, R7, R3
    //right shift R7 by k
    ASR R7, R7, R5
    //if statement 
    CMP R7, R6
    //if step >t step = t
    MOVGT R7, R6
    //else if step <-t step = -t
    //R8 for negative t
    MVN R8, R7
    ADD R8, R8, #1
    CMP R7, R8
    MOVLT R7, R8
    // xi = xi-step R3-R7
    SUB R3, R3, R7
    



    //i++
    ADD R1, #1
    B LOOP 
END:
    //store result to x
    LDR     R9, =x
    STR     R3, [R9]
```

but I'm receiving this error

Assemble: arm-altera-eabi-as -mfloat-abi=soft -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon-fp16 --gdwarf2 -
o /tmp/asm02m1B8.s.o /tmp/asm02m1B8.s

/tmp/asm02m1B8.s: Assembler messages:

/tmp/asm02m1B8.s:15: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
Compile failed.

and I cant figure out why?

Comment: My guess is `LDR R2, #0`. You probably wanted a `MOV`.

Comment: Which line is line #15?

Comment: just examine and fix the line of code, get it to save the temporary file, the error message tells you the problem, what part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Just cut and paste the code and run the assembler yourself, left at the default armv4t  so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:34: Rd and Rm should be different in mul
so.s:15: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up

Comment: change it to something newer and you just get the fixup for the ldr r2,#0 which is somewhat obvious.  try mov r2,#0 or ldr r2,=0